# Sporadic page load failure

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, pageload

An issue has started recently, within Chrome and reportedly Firefox, pages would be loading fine and browsing would be as normal and then suddenly then a page would fail to load (continuing to spin as if loading). The page that fails is often not the same.

If I refresh the page or try to goto another page on the domain within the same browser, the browser doesn't even try to resolve the name or make a connection, and is then unable to load the page.

Swapping to another browser and I am back to browsing the domain normally again, while the original browser(in most cases Chrome) will not load the pages until a restart.

This has happened with 3 different people on 3 different machines in both Chrome and Firefox.

The domain that it is running off has allot of ajax calls within certain pages, I am not sure if the server is tripping out due to the number of requests from the one client...I am not sure.

I am not sure if this is a server, client or script functionality issue, as I can not personally reproduce it. I can do little to debug or work out what is causing this or how to fix it...

As you can see I am not sure of allot with this problem :) so I am throwing it out to stack-overflow in the hope that someone may have had similar experiences or have any directions I could look towards.

Cheers,
Brendan

Comment: Hi Brendan, SO is about programming. Your question is quite off-topic here... Try it on http://superuser.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is making many requests in a short time, your firewall (router) may block it. I've noticed this behavior on my own router, and had to set it to a less restrictive level to make things work.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion, I will have a look at the firewall logs and settings see if it has anything to do with it.